# getting error while doing bulk insert using copy into command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The error reported:

```
Error parsing JSON: unknown keyword "nul" 
File 'gg-data-json/test_schema.testable/test_schema.testable_2022-02-03_02-17-42.290.json', 
line 1, character 509767681 Row 90434, column JSON_DATA 
If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. 
For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.
```

The COPY INTO command run:

```
copy into test_schema.testable 
from @test_schema.testable;
```

please suggest how to ignore this error

Comment: Are these 2 tables using variant columns or how does their definition looks like? Also a sample of the data you are trying to ingest would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by “ignore the error”? Do you want the record skipped (not loaded), or something else?